# Ruby executable runs from terminal but not from file browser

Tags: ruby, unix

I have a ruby file that I've given executable permissions and set up such that typing

```
./filename
```

works just fine. However, attempting to run the file just by double clicking it through Files either opens it in a text editor or does nothing, depending on how I've configured it through dconf-editor. How can I get it to run properly through Files?

Comment: What distro and GUI environment? Which file browser?

Comment: What happens if you rename it to `filename.rb` and try again?

Comment: Also if you are using Ubuntu, see here how to associate programs with file extensions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/289337/how-can-i-change-file-association-globally

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 using default gnome-terminal. Renaming the file doesn't change anything.